# MSSQL Lag subquery for offset

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, lag

I have the "camp" column and I want to update it to look like the "camp2" column. So for each record I want to assign the value "camp" from the last record to a given user with status 2.

Any idea how to make it? I thought about the LAG() function but unfortunately couldn't write a subquery to determine the offset..

I also care about the performance of the function, because it will have to update hundreds of thousands of records every day.

[image]

Comment: Side note, you are clearly storing delimited data in your database here; that's a really bad idea. Especially when that delimited data is numerical and thus the the value can't be stored as one. As a result, in your data, `'{2}'` has a **larger** value than `'{111}'`.

Comment: Also, please take the time to post your sample data in a **consumable** format; that means not an an image. DDL and DML statements are best, but well formatted tabular `text` are also far more useful. Along with consumable sample data, expected results will help us help you too.

Comment: And of course "camp" column, if it is not a JSON one, violate the 1FN.